# Deleting all word occurences with sed preserving linefeed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I'm trying to delete a word's all occurences in a text file with sed. I have this file f1:

> alma a fa
>   alatt
>   nyari piros alma

and I'd like to delete all occurences of "alma". I use the following in a .sh script:

```
a=`sed "s/alma//g" $ file`; 
echo -e $a | cat > $file
```

where `$file` contains the name of this text file I've just written before. The problem is that sed does not take into account the linefeed and my new f1 file looks like this:

> a fa alatt nyari piros.

So everything is written in a single line, however, I'd like to preserve the f1's original form with separate lines.
How could I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU `sed`, you can achieve this with a single command:

```
sed -i "s/alma//g" f1
```

`-i` edits the file in place.

For BSD `sed`, e.g. on OS X, options are different: you need `sed -i '' 's/alma//g' f1`.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the quotes.

```
a=$(sed "s/alma//g" $file);
printf %b "$a" > $file
```

You [should always use quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Quoting) around parameter expansion, unless you know what you are doing.

However, I think that parkydr's one-liner is more readable.

Comment: Side notes: In general, you should [prefer printf to echo](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/echo#portability_considerations). There's no reason to spawn an additional process for `cat` - redirection is fine. [$() is preferred to `](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Major-Differences-From-The-Bourne-Shell)